# Check string for substring existence

Tags: sql, string, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, sql-like

How can I check whether a certain substring (for instance `18UT`) is part of a string in a column?

Redshifts' [SUBSTRING](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SUBSTRING.html) function allows me to "cut" a certain substring based on a starting index + length of the subtring, but not check whether a specific substring exists is in the column's value.

Example:

```
+------------------+
| col              |
+------------------+
| 14TH, 14KL, 18AB |
| 14LK, 18UT, 15AK |
| 14AB, 08ZT, 18ZH |
| 14GD, 52HG, 18UT |
+------------------+
```

Desired result:

```
+------------------+------+
| col              | 18UT | 
+------------------+------+
| 14TH, 14KL, 18AB | No   |
| 14LK, 18UT, 15AK | Yes  |
| 14AB, 08ZT, 18ZH | No   |
| 14GD, 52HG, 18UT | Yes  |
+------------------+------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option:

```sql
select col,
    case when ', ' || col || ', ' like '%, 18UT, %' then 'yes' else 'no' end has_18ut
from mytable
```

While this will solve your immediate, problem, it should be note that storing delimited lists in a database table is bad practice, and should be avoided. Each value should go to a separate row instead.

Comment: Simple and elegant, thank you! I get your point and my data-heart bleeds while working with this data (especially because there are different amounts of 4-letter values in the column, from 1 to 17 different ones....), but I am not able to do much about it as of now.